# Como fazer select usando LINQ com 2 tabelas?

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu `select`:

```
bd = new AcessoBancoDados();

bd.Conectar();
string cidade = "SELECT c.Nome FROM Cidade c join Estado e on c.EstadoId   = e.EstadoId WHERE  e.Sigla = '" + dto.Estado + "'";

dt = bd.RetornDataTable(cidade);
```

Que no cadastro seleciono o estado ai ele filtra no banco todas as cidades com `id` do estado que tenha a sigla selecionada, ai envia para `Combobox` a lista das cidades.

Mas agora estou usando `lambda`, como faço essa pesquisa? eu tentei desta maneira:

```
    private void cbxEstado_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cidBLL = new CidadeBLL();
            estBLL = new EstadoBLL();
            if (cbxEstado.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                cbxCidade.Enabled = true;
                int est;
                est =  Convert.ToInt32(cbxEstado.SelectedValue);
                cbxCidade.DataSource = cidBLL.Pesquisar_Cidade(est).ToList();
            }
        }


       namespace BLL
       {
       public class CidadeBLL
       {
        ICidadeRepositorio _cidadeRepositorio;
        public CidadeBLL()
        {
            _cidadeRepositorio = new CidadeRepositorio();
        }
        public List<CidadeDTO> Pesquisar_Cidade(int estadoID)
        {

            try
            {
                return _cidadeRepositorio.Get(c => c.estadoID == estadoID).ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }

     }
     }

     namespace DAL.IRepositorio
     {
     public interface ICidadeRepositorio : IRepositorio<CidadeDTO>
    {
    }
    }

    namespace DAL.Repositorio
    {
    public class CidadeRepositorio : Repositorio<CidadeDTO>, ICidadeRepositorio
    {
    }
    }

    namespace DAL
    {
    public interface IRepositorio<T> where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetTodos();
        IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T Find(params object[] key);
        T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        void Adicionar(T entity);
        void Atualizar(T entity);
        void Deletar(Func<T, bool> predicate);
        void Commit();
        void Dispose();
    }
    }

    namespace DAL
    {
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using Model;

    public partial class NetunoEntities : DbContext
    {
        public NetunoEntities()
            : base("name=NetunoEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AberturaCaixaDTO> AberturaCaixaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CategoriaDTO> CategoriaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CidadeDTO> CidadeDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ClienteDTO> ClienteDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ContaPagarDTO> ContaPagarDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ContaReceberDTO> ContaReceberDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ControleCompraDTO> ControleCompraDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ControleVendaDTO> ControleVendaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CrediarioDTO> CrediarioDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EmpresaDTO> EmpresaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EstadoDTO> EstadoDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FechaCaixaDTO> FechaCaixaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FluxoCaixaDTO> FluxoCaixaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FormaPagDTO> FormaPagDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FornecedorDTO> FornecedorDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ItensVendaDTO> ItensVendaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MarcaDTO> MarcaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<NaturezaOpeDTO> NaturezaOpeDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<NCMDTO> NCMDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PlanoContaDTO> PlanoContaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ProdutoDTO> ProdutoDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UnidadeMedidaDTO> UnidadeMedidaDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UsuarioDTO> UsuarioDTOes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VendedorDTO> VendedorDTOes { get; set; }
     }
     }

     namespace DAL
     {
     public class Repositorio<T> : IRepositorio<T>, IDisposable where T : class
     {
        private NetunoEntities Context;

        protected Repositorio()
        {
            Context = new NetunoEntities();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetTodos()
        {
            return Context.Set<T>();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        }

        public T Find(params object[] key)
        {
            return Context.Set<T>().Find(key);
        }

        public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public void Adicionar(T entity)
        {
            Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void Atualizar(T entity)
        {
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void Deletar(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            Context.Set<T>()
           .Where(predicate).ToList()
           .ForEach(del => Context.Set<T>().Remove(del));
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Context.Dispose();
            }
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
    }

    namespace Model
    {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class CidadeDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int cidadeID { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public bool capital { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("estadoID")]
        public int estadoID { get; set; }
        public virtual EstadoDTO EstadoDTOes { get; set; }
    }
    }                    
    namespace DAL.IRepositorio
{
    public interface IEstadoRepositorio : IRepositorio<EstadoDTO>
    {
    }
}
    namespace DAL.Repositorio
{
    public class EstadoRepositorio : Repositorio<EstadoDTO>, IEstadoRepositorio
    {
    }
}


   public partial class EstadoDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int estadoID { get; set; }
    public string sigla { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CidadeDTO> CidadeDTOes { get; set; }
}
```

Mas retorna o erro;

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  The relationship
>   'NetunoModel.EstadoDTOCidadeDTO' was not loaded because the type
>   'NetunoModel.CidadeDTO' is not available. The following information
>   may be useful in resolving the previous error: The required property
>   'EstadoDTO' does not exist on the type 'Model.CidadeDTO'.

RESOLVI JA **return _cidadeRepositorio.Get(c => c.estadoID == estadoID).ToList();**

Comment: O _cidadeRepositorio é uma lista?

Comment: _cidadeRepositorio e objeto de ICidadeRepositorio

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou usar LINQ? ficaria mais ou menos assim desse jeito:

```
return _cidadeRepositorio.Where(c => c.estadoID == estadoID).ToList();
```

Ou assim:

```
return _cidadeRepositorio.Where(c => c.estadoID == EstadoID).ToFirst();
```

Pelo oque você postou a respeito do `lambda` me parece correto, oque você pode fazer é acrescentar a propriedade `EstadoID` a classe `CidadeDTO`, pois apenas no comando o `lambda` não o encontra.

Comment: public partial class CidadeDTO
    {
        public int cidadeID { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public int? estadoID { get; set; }
        public bool capital { get; set; }
    }  
to pegando estadoID diretto do combobox
est =  Convert.ToInt32(cbxEstado.SelectedValue);
                cbxCidade.DataSource = cidBLL.Pesquisar_Cidade(est).ToList();\
e esta classe, alterei aki pra passar estadoID di

Comment: ta dando esse erro agora  The entity type CidadeDTO is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: Esse erro ocorre quando a classe que você criou não está dentro do Contexto, há uma classe Context que tem herança da classe dbContext, e dentro dela você mapeia a classe do tipo Cidade DTO, a partir dessa classe você pode mapear todas as sua entidades(suas classes de banco),segue um link para ficar mais claro: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx

Comment: esse e meu select e outro projeto SELECT c.Nome FROM Cidade c join Estado e on c.EstadoId = e.EstadoId WHERE  e.Sigla = '" + dto.Estado + "'"

como eu fasso select em lambda
public List<CidadeDTO> Pesquisar_Cidade(int estadoID)
        {
            try
            {
                return _cidadeRepositorio.Get(c => c.estadoID == estadoID).ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }

da classe repositorio
IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

Comment: classe public partial class EstadoDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int estadoID { get; set; }
        public string sigla { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CidadeDTO> CidadeDTOes { get; set; }
    }


classe
   public partial class CidadeDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int cidadeID { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public bool capital { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("estadoID")]
        public int estadoID { get; set; }
        public virtual EstadoDTO EstadoDTOes { get; set; }
    }